# Unable to deserialize polymorphic list from xml

Tags: c#, xsd, xmlserializer, xsd2code

I deserialize from an xml file using XmlSerializer over classes generated by Xsd2Code from an xsd file with elements extending a base element.

Here is a simplified example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
<xs:complexType name="Vehicle" abstract="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
  </xs:sequence>   
</xs:complexType>   
<xs:complexType name="Car">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Vehicle">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Configuration" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Truck">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Vehicle">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Load" type="xs:int" nillable="false" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Garage">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Vehicles" type="Vehicle" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="false" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Generated code:

```
public partial class Garage
{
    public Garage()
    {
        Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
    }

    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}    
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Truck))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Car))]
public partial class Vehicle
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}    
public partial class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public int Load { get; set; }
}    
public partial class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Garage>
  <Vehicles>
    <Vehicle>
      <Manufacturer>Honda</Manufacturer>
      <Configuration>Sedan</Configuration>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle>
      <Manufacturer>Volvo</Manufacturer>
      <Load>40</Load>
    </Vehicle>
  </Vehicles>
</Garage>
```

And the deserializing code:

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Garage));

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("Settings.xml"))
{
    var garage = (Garage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    var car = garage.Vehicles[0] as Car;
    Console.WriteLine(car.Configuration);
}
```

I get an exception `The specified type is abstract: name='Vehicle', namespace='', at <Vehicle xmlns=''>.` on the deserializing line.

If I remove the abstract attribute from the Vehicle element in XSD I get a null reference exception because `garage.Vehicles[0]` cannot be cast to `Car`.

I want to be able to deserialize and then cast into `Car` and `Truck`. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that your XML does not match your XSD.  If you try to validate the XML using .Net (sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AUzjig)) you will see the following errors:

```
The element 'Vehicles' is abstract or its type is abstract.
The element 'Vehicles' has invalid child element 'Vehicle'. List of possible elements expected: 'Manufacturer'.
```

These errors have the following meaning:

- `The element 'Vehicles' has invalid child element 'Vehicle'. List of possible elements expected: 'Manufacturer'.`

  The problem here is that your XSD specifies that the `<Vehicles>` list does not have a container element.  Instead, it should just be a repeating set of elements like so:

  ```
  <Garage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vehicles>
      <Manufacturer>Honda</Manufacturer>
      <Configuration>Sedan</Configuration>
    </Vehicles>
    <Vehicles>
      <Manufacturer>Volvo</Manufacturer>
      <Load>40</Load>
    </Vehicles>
  </Garage>
  ```

  For which the corresponding c# class is:

  ```
  public partial class Garage
  {
      public Garage()
      {
          Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
      }

      [XmlElement]
      public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  To specify an outer wrapper element with inner elements named `<Vehicle>`, your XSD would have to have an extra intermediate element `ArrayOfVehicle`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
  <xs:complexType name="Vehicle" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
    </xs:sequence>   
  </xs:complexType>   
  <xs:complexType name="Car">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Vehicle">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Configuration" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Truck">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Vehicle">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Load" type="xs:int" nillable="false" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <!-- BEGIN CHANGES HERE -->
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfVehicle">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Vehicle" nillable="true" type="Vehicle" />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Garage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Vehicles" type="ArrayOfVehicle" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <!-- END CHANGES HERE -->
  </xs:schema>
  ```

  In your question, you wrote *Here is a simplified example*.  Is there a chance the extra level of nesting in the XSD was manually omitted when writing the question?
- `The element 'Vehicles' is abstract or its type is abstract.`

  You are trying to serialize a polymorphic list by specifying possible subtypes using [`XmlIncludeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx).

  When doing this, it is necessary for each polymorphic element in the XML to assert its actual type using the w3c standard attribute [`xsi:type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) (short for `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type`), as is explained in [Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx).  Only then will `XmlSerializer` know the correct, concrete type to which to deserialize each element.  Thus your final XML should look like:

  ```
  <Garage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vehicles xsi:type="Car">
      <Manufacturer>Honda</Manufacturer>
      <Configuration>Sedan</Configuration>
    </Vehicles>
    <Vehicles xsi:type="Truck">
      <Manufacturer>Volvo</Manufacturer>
      <Load>40</Load>
    </Vehicles>
  </Garage>
  ```

  Or, if you prefer to have an outer wrapper element for your vehicle collection:

  ```
  <Garage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Vehicles>
      <Vehicle xsi:type="Car">
        <Manufacturer>Honda</Manufacturer>
        <Configuration>Sedan</Configuration>
      </Vehicle>
      <Vehicle xsi:type="Truck">
        <Manufacturer>Volvo</Manufacturer>
        <Load>40</Load>
      </Vehicle>
    </Vehicles>
  </Garage>
  ```

  The latter XML can be successfully deserialized into your current `Garage` class without errors, as is shown [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AUzjig).

Incidentally, an easy way to debug this sort of problem is to create an instance of your `Garage` class in memory, populate its vehicle list, and serialize it.  Having done so, you would have seen inconsistencies with the XML you were trying to deserialize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed there's a nesting issue I overlooked when adding this simplified example, the true code has the correct nesting level in both xsd and xml. I eventually opted for the same xsi:type solution you suggested. This works fine for me because my xml holds a short collection of "Vehicles", but I wonder, what would one do for a huge collection? Could be a maintenance nightmare.